# Calendar with database SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to programming an schedule in C# where I want to show all my tasks, for example:
01-20-2018 at 3pm meeting with boss. And have a question:

Should I create a table "task" where i save the date my id and boss id?
Would it overload the dB?

I need some tips, thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for advice on the database schema?  Can you provide any additional information about what makes up a Task and what you want to do with them?  For example, do you want to be able to send reminder emails to the attendees, etc.  At this point, I would suggest having one table, `Task` for the definition of the task (`Id`, `Title`, `Description`, `Date`) and another table, `TaskAttendee` to associate an Attendee with a task.

Comment: Hi Aaron, It's a Schedule for manage a teacher tasks and I want to show at the calendar when he looks for example the tasks for tomorrow ok? Then He looks if he has class at 8 am until 9pm if   He has class then show which class that he has but i think that your tip will be usefull. Unless you  want add anything! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many interlocutors (bosses) will you have ? Certainly more than one.

I suggest you should have one table for each purpose :
A task_table for tasks with an ID_Task as primary key, Detail field, delay field, status field and son on.
A target_table for the targets which is/are involved in the task with an ID_target (primary key) with a name field, first name field, company field, observation field and whatever field you need.

And you link this two tables in an another one :

Rendezvous_table, with Id_rendezvous (primary key), datetimestamp field, Id_Task field, Id_target field and observation_field for observation on rendezvous.

This can be a good start. Beware the relations one to multiple, one to one,  multiple to multiple. Multiple task for a same rendez-vous, only one interlocutor for one rendez-vous or multiple...

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will try it! I will tell you something if it works, probably yes! Thank you so much, kontiki! ;)